# Firebase cannot find setter if the setter is an overridden method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a base class that stores a field called updatedAt and a setter setUpdatedAt. There is a child class Child. I know that Firebase cannot find setter in the parent classes, so I just define the setter setUpdatedAt again in Child, but I am still getting "No setter/field for updatedAt found on class xxx.Child"

My database json has that "updatedAt" field.

Sample code:

```
public abstract class Model {
  private String mId;
  private long mUpdatedAt;

  public String getId() {return mId;}
  public void setId(String id) { mId = id;}
  public long getUpdatedAt() {return mUpdatedAt;}
  public void setUpdatedAt(long updatedAt) { mUpdatedAt = updatedAt;}
}

public abstract class Child extends Model {
  private String mCreator;
   public String getCreator() {
        return mCreator;
    }

    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        mCreator = creator;
    }
  // having the following or not does not change the outcome
  public void setUpdatedAt(long updatedAt) {
        super.setUpdatedAt(updatedAt);
    }
}

// then somewhere else, do this
new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Child.class);
}
```

And I got "No setter/field for updatedAt found on class xxx.Child" and "No setter/field for id found on class xxx.Child" when "model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Child.class);" is executed.

For actual code sample, see github [MinFirebaseApp](https://github.com/hermantai/samples/tree/master/android/MinFirebaseApp). In MainActivity, you can see the two methods "createEmployee" and "showEmployee", which shows how an employee is created in "createEmployee" and the same employee is fetched in "showEmployee". Using the code, you can reproduce it by (after you change the package id to yours):

1. Put the google-services.json file in the app folder
2. Start the app
3. Click on "login" to sign in anonymously
4. Click on "create employee", see that the employee is created
5. Go to console.firebase.google.com to check that the employee is
   created with id, name and updatedAt
6. Click on "show employee" from the app, see the "updatedAt" and "id"
   are not set.
7. Check the logcat to find something like "No setter/field for id found" and "No setter/field for updatedAt found"

Comment: Instead of describing your code, include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question please.

Comment: Added code sample, thanks.

Comment: Added github code sample as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to call through to *all* of your setters in the subclass.  You may as well do the getters too.  Right now you're just doing setUpdatedAt(), but there is setId() as well.  This is a bug in the Android client library for Realtime Database, but the team is working on a fix that will be available in the future.

Comment: Interesting, I found that overriding the getters as well makes it works! Thanks.